# How to check what an obfuscated program does?

Tags: javascript, analysis, virus

It's most likely a virus: I got it from a local chicken shop website, asking me to update Firefox as it was apparently out of date. Which it wasn't, but okay. I clicked the thing because why not, and it downloaded a .JS file.

The file itself is seemingly a pile of gibberish, here's the first line:

`(function(wyfdysu){var iwtquom="arwob"["c"+("H","q","n","o")+["U","n","H","H"][(-`

So yeah, aside from a VM, is there any way I can safely inspect this?

Answer (score 0):

Typically malicious websites use so-called [Drive-by Downloads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive-by_download) to get you to download their exploits onto your system. From there on they often use remote code execution to read and write data from your PC. This may be the case with you.

### Inspecting the file

As it only downloaded a .JS file, you can safely inspect it with a text editor on your current system. You can also try to find an exploit that used the same technique on [Exploit-DB](https://www.exploit-db.com/) or searching the code in question on Google. Best bet though would be to [hexdump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump) it on a VM and try to reverse engineer your way to see what it does if you can't find any more information on the code.

### Take aways

- Never grant a malicious website access to files and privileges that they could exploit
- Never allow a malicious website to download a file for you.

Comment: I presume modern browsers and anti-virus prevent actual drive-bys, right? I'd need to launch the .JS for anything malicious to happen, no?

Comment: @Mox Modern browsers and anti-virus' do not prevent drive-by downloads for non-binary files per se. Your anti-virus software should detect any malicious shellcode that is run on your computer though. Some anti-virus' detect via the comparision of static signatures and others track the pattern of the shellcode.